# Spring boot(2.2 MI) Security : Configure custom AuthenticationFailureHandler for HttpBasic

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

My Spring Boot ( Version 2.2 MI) application is having only REST endpoints authenticated with httpBasic using spring security. But, when the user authentication fails due to user not being enabled etc, I would like to respond with the custom Json so that my React Native app guide the user appropriately. But, custom AuthenticationFailureHandler seems to be configurable only for formLogin.

I see examples only like

```
http.
   formLogin().
       failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler());

public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler
   implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
       @Override
       public void onAuthenticationFailure(
           HttpServletRequest request,
           HttpServletResponse response,
           AuthenticationException exception)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
       }
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}
```

But, I need something like below (which is not seesm to be there)

```
http.
   httpBasic().
       failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler());
```

Please let me know, whats the best way to go forward ?

Update :-
As per the accepted answer below, below is the custom implementation CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + this.getRealmName() + "\"");
        //response.sendError( HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Test msg response");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("{ \"val\":\"Venkatesh\"}");
    }
}

@Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint obj = new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        obj.setRealmName("YourAppName");
        return obj;
    }

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.httpBasic().
                authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `BasicAuthenticationFilter` fails to authenticate , it will call `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. The default one is `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`, you can consider to write a custom one or extend it :

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
}
```

And configure it by :

```
   http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())
```